# Best migration strategy for Struts 2.1.6+Spring 3+Hibernate 3 to java 8 supported versions

Tags: spring, hibernate, java-8, struts2, migration

Currently I have one web-application built upon the frameworks ***Struts 2.1.6+Spring 3+Hibernate 3+JAVA 6*** and running on ***Tomcat 6/JBoss 5***. It is a very old application with **ant build**, but now we have a requirement of upgrade this to ***JAVA 8*** and ***EAP 7 and Tomcat 9*** server.

I did the following steps, but need more reworks to make it runnable

1. First upgraded `JAVA 6 to 8` - then spring dependencies failed to instantiate
2. Then upgraded `Spring 3.x to latest 5.1.7.RELEASE` - now the hibernate template and all got failed because of the change like `*.hibernate5.*` package changes and all - done some code changes to fix it
3. Upgraded `Hibernate 3.x to 5.4.2.Final` - added some changes deprecated codes
4. Upgraded `struts2-spring-plugin-2.1.6 to struts2-spring-plugin-2.5.20` to support with new spring version
5. Now at the time of publishing to **Tomcat 9**, com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.classloader.* shown missing. So I have upgraded `xwork-core 2.1.2 to 2.3.37`. But after that error changed to `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.addConfigurationProvider`. Then I have downgraded the version `xwork-core-2.3.3` where this function was last existing as deprecated, but then got the new error like

```
Caused by: com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$MissingDependencyException: No mapping found for dependency [type=java.lang.String, name='struts.objectFactory.spring.enableAopSupport'] in public org.apache.struts2.spring.StrutsSpringObjectFactory(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,javax.servlet.ServletContext,java.lang.String,com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.Container).
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.createParameterInjector(ContainerImpl.java:239)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.getParametersInjectors(ContainerImpl.java:229)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$ConstructorInjector.constructParameterInjector(ContainerImpl.java:361)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$ConstructorInjector.<init>(ContainerImpl.java:345)
```

Now when searching, I am getting the solutions like to **upgrade struts** also and found there is **version 2.5.x** version available. But in this version there seems to be removed many old items like `**dojo plugin**`, so I have to do more reworks on the existing codes which will take many man days.

I am expecting a less impact suggestion and solutions with minimum code changes for upgrade since the application is already live running.

Comment: This is why it's best to use a dependency manager so you don't have to do most of this work manually. The Dojo tags were deprecated *years* ago, and replacing them with plain jQuery (or the jQuery plugin, or other solution) is generally straight-forward. You'll spend just as many days manually updating your app anyway.

Comment: Yes, I agreed with you, doing manual updates is not a good option. But currently the project contains multiple modules having many circular dependencies - the source base is very old. So need some refactoring of code to make it work with dependency manager like maven multi-module. But at this point the problem here is the compatibility(Struts 2.1.6+Spring 5) issue for the jar version struts2-spring-plugin-*.jar

Comment: Many things changed from the old version to the current and you have to hard work to rewrite the legacy app which is using a new struts2.